# PaperclipError, "There was an error processing the thumbnail for ..."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I'm on Windows 7 running Ruby 1.8.7 with Rails 2.3.5.

When I upload a picture in a web-application (not written by me) I get this error:

> [paperclip] identify -format %wx%h "C:/Windows/Temp/stream20110104-3660-1j1ap8i-0.jpg[0]" 2>NUL
>
> [paperclip] convert "C:/Windows/Temp/stream20110104-3660-1j1ap8i-0.jpg[0]" -resize "100x140>" "C:/Windows/Temp/stream20110104-3660-1j1ap8i-020110104-3660-rmkivh-0" 2>NUL
>
> [paperclip] An error was received while processing: There was an error processing the
> thumbnail for...

When I try the convert-command in the cmd-shell it works.
I installed the web-application to two virtual machines and a server (all Win 7) and get the error everywhere.

On another PC (Win 7 as well) with the same configuration though its working fine.

Do you know what may cause this problem?

This is the code in the thumbnail.rb which produces this error:

```
    # Performs the conversion of the +file+ into a thumbnail. Returns the Tempfile
# that contains the new image.
def make
  src = @file
  dst = Tempfile.new([@basename, @format ? ".#{@format}" : ''])
  dst.binmode

  begin
    parameters = []
    parameters << source_file_options
    parameters << ":source"
    parameters << transformation_command
    parameters << convert_options
    parameters << ":dest"

    parameters = parameters.flatten.compact.join(" ").strip.squeeze(" ")

    success = Paperclip.run("convert", parameters, :source => "#{File.expand_path(src.path)}[0]", :dest => File.expand_path(dst.path))
  rescue PaperclipCommandLineError => e
    raise PaperclipError, "There was an error processing the thumbnail for #{@basename}" if @whiny
  end

  dst
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have ImageMagick installed? Is it in your system PATH?

Comment: Yes and yes. I tried the same convert-command as in the log in the shell which worked fine.

Answer (score 4):

Windows has it's own `convert` tool, so ImageMagick needs to be put higher in the `PATH` than System32 folder.

Verify that if the application is running with the same `PATH` as you other command line. If you're running it as a service, there is a chance is not.

Also, verify that the temporary file generate can be processed by you manually. In the output there is no indication of the details of the failure, it just say it failed.

Try running the same command as soon the error happen. From the output is not clear what happened. Also see if identify is *identifying* the file properly.

Comment: Rearranging the path-entries solved the problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hmn, weird that you found this helped and yet still awarded the answer to other post :(

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread but I had this same problem. ImageMagicK was installed and running properly and rearranging the PATH variables didn't help. Turns out all I needed to do was close the CMD shell from where I was running 'rails server' and reopen it. I hadn't done so since installing imagemagick and paperclip and new PATH variables aren't available until the CMD shell you're working from is reinitialized.

Answer (score 0):

You can define path to ImageMagick somewhere in /config/initializers

```
case Config::CONFIG['host_os']
    when /darwin/   # MacOS & macports
        Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin"
    when /mswin|mingw/  # Windows
        Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "Your path "
end
```